# Retain None in pandas DataFrame (in spite of astype() and to_parquet())

Tags: python, pandas, types, null, parquet

How can I force a pandas DataFrame to retain `None` values, even when using `astype()`?

### Details

Since the `pd.DataFrame` constructor offers no compound `dtype` parameter, I fix the types (required for `to_parquet()`) with the following function:

```
def _typed_dataframe(data: list) -> pd.DataFrame:
    typing = {
        'name': str,
        'value': np.float64,
        'info': str,
        'scale': np.int8,
    }    
    result = pd.DataFrame(data)
    for label in result.keys():
        result[label] = result[label].astype(typing[label])
    return result
```

Unfortunately, `result[info] = result[info].astype(str)` transforms all `None` values in `info` to `"None"` strings. How can I forbid this, i.e. retain `None` values?

To be more precise: `None` values in `data` become `np.nan` in the `result` DataFrame, which become `"nan"` by `astype(str)`, which become `"None"` when extracted from `result`.

Comment: Assuming you are using pandas-1.0, what you can do is use `string` datatype instead of `str` datatype. What it's gonna do is like preserve all the NaN values as a nullable integer type `<NA>`. So it'll be like:
`result[info] = result[info].astype("string")`

Comment: @frosty: interesting, I did not know pandas had a datatype `string` (+1). Will the corresponding Parquet format be compatible to the one with `str`? As that is what the Parquet consumers expect for `info`. If so, this is a great simple solution worth as answer!

Comment: I am not very expert when it comes to parquet format but I tried writing that parquet using pandas after casting type as `StringDType/string` and while reading the same file in Jupyter notebook, my notebook kernel dies which is very weird. But to check if it's reading it as string, I read it in pyspark and checked it's schema and yes it's retaining the null values and format for casted column is `string`.
I will still have to figure out why kernel keeps on dieing while reading parquet in pandas, may be you can try running it once at your end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @frosty's comment, we can use the alternative

```
    typing = {
        'name': str,
        'value': np.float64,
        'info': pd.StringDtype(),
        'scale': np.int8,
    }
```

However, this requires `pandas ~= 1.0.0`.

---

<s>As better solution, you can replace</s>

```
for label in result.keys():
    result[label] = result[label].astype(typing[label])
```

by

```
result.astype(schema)
```

Unfortunately, `result.astype(typing)` has no effect since it cannot handle compound types.

Comment: thanks, this one saved the day for me